# Axios getting empty response objects for GET request in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, axios

while sending a `GET` request using Axios, it works well in all other browsers, However I am getting this data in IE11

```
{
    request: {
    },
    headers: {
    },
    config: {
    },
    statys: 200,
    statusText: "OK"
}
```

`request, headers and config` are empty objects in the response object of the Axios request. Expecting headers, request and config data in the object (This is working well in Chrome)

Not really sure why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include a promise polyfill if the browser has no promise implementation which IE11 does not.

The axios docs mention it: axios depends on a native ES6 Promise implementation to be supported. If your environment doesn't support ES6 Promises, you can polyfill.

Check out the ES6 promise polyfill here: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: shouldn't it be throwing error if the issue is with promise? I am using Promise polyfill though, and there are no errors in the console. Getting response in a then callback, the structure of the JSON is mentioned above.

Comment: Try to add code below to to your app may help to fix the issue. _beforeRequest(config) { config.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'; config.cache = false; config.headers.get = {}; config.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0'; ....... } Ref: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1293